# GTA SA - Freefall Mission, better way to catch the plane?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I've played GTA SA on both PC & Mac, first when it was new & again last year, from scratch, no cheats.

Every time, though, I get stuck at the Freefall mission & spend days getting to the airport, flying for 5 minutes to find the airplane I'm supposed to jump to, only to never quite be able to catch it.

It gets a bit tedious after the 10th attempt & I give up.
Last time I gave up at this point is nearly a year ago, so I thought I'd see if there's any easier way to do this mission.

My flying skill is high, I've completed all the flying school missions (though I don't actually think I'm a great pilot)

Is there just some simple trick I'm missing?
Is there any sure-fire way to complete this level (quickly)?
I've tried flying higher than the plane & diving down to it, which occasionally gets me closer, but it's so hit & miss.

Anything, any way to be able to complete this one & one time be able to finish the game.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about when you have to fly into the Corona?

Comment: That's the one, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Shamal is faster than the airplane you're given. To counter that, pay attention to the minimap (or open the world map), and predict where the Shamal is heading (it will not go always in a straight line).

This allows you to get closer to it , until you're right on top of it, and flying *through* the Corona is simply a matter of adjusting your position slightly. Ideally you should keep your height high since descending is easier than ascending.

Once again, the trick is **don't follow the plane**, intercept it.

Comment: This is 'the correct' answer. I tested it & it works. Before I read it, I did however find how to cheat the level :/ SO I've now done it both ways, this way & mine, which I shall post below. [I won't include the details as to how, as that would appear to be off-topic]

Comment: @Tetsujin feel free to answer with alternative methods (even if they involve cheating), because it may also help someone else down the line. The more (useful) answers we have the better.

Comment: I did. It was deleted.

Comment: @Tetsujin I guess some people are just horny to get their review badges :/

Comment: tbh, if a mod deletes it, even when I referred to the specific meta about posting cheats... tbh, I no longer care. I'll not bother again if that's they kind of response you get in this SE. It's not like I'm a newbie. I'd have binned the question too, but you can't one it's answered/